# Displaying MySQL DOB Records Between Now and XX Days

Tags: mysql

I am looking to pull records from my MySQL database where the DAY of the date-of-birth (dob) is between now and XX many days away.  For example, show all birthdays that are between now and 15 days from now. I am using the formula below and it works until today's date gets closer to the end of the month. So, if today is June 1, and I want to pull all the birthdays between now and 15 days...it works fine. But If today was June 25, it would say that no records are found as end of the 15 days is in another month.

```
SELECT contacts._id FROM `contacts` LEFT JOIN `groups` ON groups._id = "2"
WHERE (DAY(`dob`) BETWEEN DAY(CURDATE())
AND DAY(ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15 DAY))
AND MONTH(`dob`) BETWEEN MONTH(CURDATE())
AND MONTH(ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL15 DAY))
```

I have also tried using something like the code below, but it does not work with DOB data as years prior to the current year will never be found. So, the year must be ignored.

```
SELECT contacts._id FROM `contacts` LEFT JOIN `groups` ON groups._id = "2"
WHERE dob BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + 15
```

The dates are stored in the DB as 2012-08-27, 1982-06-18, 1963-07-26, etc. I am only interested in the MONTH-DAY information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your dates are already stored in date format, just add 15 days to the current date so you are finding results that fall between that range:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_col BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)
```

Comment: That is the problem. If I use the CURDATE() type query, it will not pickup any dates older than today. So for example, 1984-02-02 will never be between today and any future date...unless I am able to strip the YEAR.

Comment: Whoops. Try WHERE SUBSTR(date_col, 6, 5) BETWEEN SUBSTR(CURDATE(), 6, 5) AND SUBSTR(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15 DAY), 6, 5)

Answer (score 1):

Use `DAYOFYEAR()` and `MAKEDATE()`:

```
SELECT
    a._id
FROM 
    contacts a
LEFT JOIN
    groups b ON b._id = 2
WHERE
    MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW() + INTERVAL 15 DAY), DAYOFYEAR(a.dob)) BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 15 DAY
```

**Explanation:**

`MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW() + INTERVAL 15 DAY), DAYOFYEAR(a.dob))`

This gets the date of birth in terms of what day of the year it's in (1 to 365 or 366), but in the context of the current year (or the next year if the 15 day range falls between two years).

Say the date of birth was `1986-07-04`. It would create `2012-07-04`, and the comparison that it falls between now and 15 days from now is simple.